# Cut off x-axis label problem in multiple plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on making multiple distribution plots using `matplotlib` and `seaborn` library.

To be specific I try to put 16(= 4 x 4) plots in 1 figure.

The thing is x-axis label look cut off like as below.

[image]

How should i adrress this problem?

I wrote code as below.

```
array = aa_il.values

a = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
b = [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3]

f, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(15, 10), sharex=False)

for each, i, j in zip(np.unique(array[:,7])[:20], a, b):
    sns.distplot(pd.DataFrame(array[array[:,7] == each,:]).rename(columns = {9 : each})[each].astype('int64'), color="blue", ax=axes[i, j])
```

Answer (score 2):

`plt.tight_layout()` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can just change the figsize:

```
fig, ((ax0,ax1),(ax2,ax3))=plt.subplots(nrows=2,
                                       ncols=2,
                                       figsize=(7,4))
```

it will defiantly help